# Objective-c syntax trouble

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Currently i am trying to figure out what the 4-th line does:

```
- (DDFigure *)getFigureAtCell:(NSUInteger)cellNum {  
for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {  
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[DDFigure class]]) {  
        DDFigure *figure = (DDFigure *)view;  
        if (figure.cell == cellNum) {  
            return figure;  
        }  
    }  
  }  
   return nil;  
}
```

Will be vary grateful, if somebody could explain me that, cause I have no idea how to search it in documentation.

Also, is there any difference if I write:

```
- (DDFigure *)getFigureAtCell:(NSUInteger)cellNum {  
for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {  
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[DDFigure class]]) {    
        if (view.cell == cellNum) {  
            return view;  
        }  
    }  
  }  
   return nil;  
}
```

thanks for reading this.

Comment: What's the forth line exactly? `DDFigure *figure = (DDFigure *)view; `? It's just a cast. It tells the compiler "Don't worry, I say that it's a `DDFigure` object" in order to access its properties/methods (like `cell`) which aren't present in its super class (in our case, `UIView` doesn't have a property `cell`).

Comment: @Larme thank you vary much, it is exactly what i need.

Comment: Did you try the 2nd way? It didn't work, did it? So yes, there is a difference.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, it was quite stupid of me to ask before to try it (it didn't work). Thanks for pointing out the same question with answers.